# how to count the number of times a statement has been executed in mysql?

Tags: mysql, general-log

I want to sort the results in a
descending order of the total number of times each statement has been executed.

Statements executed:

```
SELECT CONVERT (argument USING utf8)
FROM mysql.general_log
WHERE argument LIKE '%SELECT%' 
OR argument LIKE '%INSERT%' 
OR argument LIKE '%DELETE%' 
OR argument LIKE '%UPDATE%';
```

Comment: You can't get the number of times without using `COUNT()`, and to do that you'll need a `GROUP BY`, and then to sort, you'll need an `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`SELECT argument, count(*)   FROM mysql.general_log     WHERE argument LIKE '%SELECT%'      OR argument LIKE '%INSERT%'      OR argument LIKE '%DELETE%'      OR argument LIKE '%UPDATE%'     GROUP BY argument     ORDER BY count(*)  desc`